# why does MappedStringIndex not included in fieldList in Mapper

Tags: lift, mapper

In Mapper's having String as a primary Key, why is the **MappedStringIndex not shown** in the list of all fields that are obtained via the **`Mapper's allFields` method**

My Mapper goes like this ...

```
class DummyMapper extends KeyedMapper[String,DummyMapper] {

  def getSingleton = DummyMapper
  def primaryKeyField = dummyCode

  object dummyCode extends MappedStringIndex(this,5)
  {
    override def writePermission_? = true
    override def dbAutogenerated_? = false
    override def dbNotNull_? = true
    override def dbColumnName="dummy_code"
  }
.....
```

I even tried it including in the `fieldOrder`. Still the result was same, **it din't showed** up in `DummyMapper.allFields` list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

primarykey fields ( of any data-type ) are **not included** in the list returned by `allFileds` method of the Mapper.

You can prepend the field separately if you want

something like

```
   var myMapperPrimaryKey=DummyMapper.primaryKeyField
   var fieldList=DummyMapper.allFields.toBuffer[BaseField]
   fieldList.prepend(myMapperPrimaryKey)

// Now fieldList is having the primaryKey along with other fields.
```